# jquery date range datepicker format

Tags: jquery, uidatepicker

I am having trouble figuring out how to set the format for the date range. I am new to jquery and I learned how to set the single datepicker, I am just having trouble with the date range. Here is the function

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my setup function for the datapicker - I found that it was hard work setting dates that were a long way from the current date but the control allows you to turn both the month and year into dropdowns so it's much easier to select a wide range of dates.  You can set the forward and backward range of the year combo with the yearRange parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
Date.format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '-90:+5'
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

```
set { minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" }
```

or use

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) });

$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ maxDate: '+1m +1w' });
```

[Reference](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate)